# How do I flush output appended to a file by a bash function/loop in real-time?

Tags: command-line, bash

My issue is that I have a function call it `function1` which runs indefinitely. The function itself echo's `hello` every second. Using the command:

```
function1 >> temp.txt
```

Every second if I am to view the file `temp.txt` I should see a new line with `hello`. However what's happening is that the function doesn't write to the file until its finished running. Therefore if I am to kill the function nothing will be written. Does anyone know of something I can do in this situation that will basically dynamically update `temp.txt`?

I have a python script set up the following way:

```
while [1>0]:
   print "hello"
   time.sleep(1)
```

Therefore this will always be running. Now I call this in a bash script

```
python pythonscript.py >> temp.txt
```

If I `kill` the process no data is logged.

Comment: Please include the source/context of function1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't buffer, but python will buffer if output isn't going to a terminal (because it's more efficient), so you'll want to flush stdout after every line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
while True:
    print "hello"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```